# Windows Server 2008 R2 w/ Remote Desktop Services very slow mapping WebDAV sharepoint drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint, remote-desktop-services, webdav

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 standard with Remote Desktop services enabled (5 user license, but generally only one or two people are using it).

The user maps a drive to a sharepoint server, using the WebDAV protocol (\server.domain.com@SSL@8443\DavWWWRoot). The sharepoint server is 2010.

Access the folders from explorer using that mapped drive is extremely slow. So every getting of a file list to display in explorer is very slow.

From other machines, even within the same network, this is not a problem.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Are the RDS and the SharePoint servers on the same local network?

Comment: @joeqwerty, yes